# Copy variable within a column to a new cell

Tags: excel, powershell, keyword-search

I've exported my Java processes to include the 'Command Line' column. The file is in a .cvs file using the following powershell script:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "name like '%java.exe'"|select ProcessName,@{Name='WorkingSet (KB)';Expression={($_.WS/1KB)}},ProcessId,CommandLine|ft -AutoSize
```

Each java.exe is unique (obviously) and the only way I've found to identify where it points is by looking in the Command Line argument for the Appserver directory.

```
(Install_Directory)\AppServer\Profiles\AppSrv01\*\Configuration.
```

The '*' variable is the key, and the information within the command line has this same information in the argument. I need to copy the variable to a new cell

In the end i'll delete the Command Line column so I just see ProcessName, WorkSet, ProcessID, and Domain. Domain is the last piece that I need.

Whether this is an extension of my existing powershell or if there is a something I can put into excel to copy everything that is between the 'AppSrv01' and 'Configuration' to a new cell.

Comment: can u post a sample of your csv with one row?

Answer (score 0):

You could **replace** not needed values like this:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "name like '%java.exe'"|
select ProcessName,
       @{Name='WorkingSet (KB)';Expression={($_.WS/1KB)}},
       ProcessId,
       CommandLine,
       @{Name='Domain';Expression={$_.CommandLine -replace [Regex]::Escape('(Install_Directory)\AppServer\Profiles\AppSrv01') -replace [Regex]::Escape('\Configuration')}}|ft -AutoSize
```

Make sure to replace correct value instead of **(Install_Directory)**